# iFrame not rendering fully from Chrome v.41 up

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

We use an iFrame on our site which sporadically displays all blank or partly blank since we moved up from Chrome v.40.
Resizing the browser window, or sometimes moving the mouse pointer around the screen makes the content render fully.
Here's the HTML for the iFrame:

```
<iframe src="homepage.do" frameborder="0" name="iframe" id="iframe" scrolling="no">
                <p>Your browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Here's a sample of what it looks like (this is a sample of where most of the frame is blank):

[image]

The iFrame gets updated dynamically using javascript/JQuery :

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', myLink);
```

Anyone have any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a Chrome bug. There is [a pending issue at the Chromium project page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=481922) about this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the issue on Chromium project page.  Someone on there recently posted a work around which has fixed the problem for me:  Adding the following css to the iFrame tag : iframe { position:relative; }